# Does Groovy have dedicated syntax for find element in collection or throw exception if not found?

Tags: groovy

Currently in Groovy I need to write the following to implement simple logic:

```
def sampleList = [1, 2]
def element = sampleList.find { it == 3 }
if (!element) {
    throw new IllegalStateException('Element not found!')
}
```

Using Java Streams it's only a bit simpler:

```
def sampleList = [1, 2]
sampleList.stream().filter { it == 3 }.findFirst().orElseThrow {
    new IllegalStateException('Element not found!')
}
```

Is there any other concise Groovy syntax to perform the same task?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
I think this is the clearest, leveraging the `Optional` API:

```
def sampleList = [1, 2]
def element = Optional.ofNullable(sampleList.find{it==3}).orElseThrow{new IllegalStateException('Element not found!')}
```

**Option 2**

I don't think this is great, but you can invoke the `throw` from a closure, and use the elvis `?:` operator

```
def sampleList = [1, 2]
def element = sampleList.find{it==3} ?: {throw new IllegalStateException('Element not found!')}()
//Alternately: ...{throw new IllegalStateException('Element not found!')}.call() to make it more readable
```

throws:

```
Exception thrown

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Element not found!
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at ConsoleScript20$_run_closure2.doCall(ConsoleScript20:2)
    at ConsoleScript20$_run_closure2.doCall(ConsoleScript20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at ConsoleScript20.run(ConsoleScript20:2)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor218.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

in groovy console

**Option 3**
Another option is extracting all the logic into a named closure:

```
def sampleList = [1, 2]
def tester = {list, value -> if(value in list){value} else{throw new IllegalStateException('Element not found!')}}

tester(sampleList, 3)
```